# Check if list values exist in multiple fields (with wildcard)

Tags: r, filter

I have a large dataset I am looking to tidy before doing some analysis in R. It is laid out as such:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c("A","B","C","D"),Code1=c("Z84","Z85","Y94","Y94"),Code2=c("","","","Z84"))
```

I have a lookup code list which I want to check against multiple columns e.g. code 1 and code 2. The complication is that it contains a wildcard as well.

```
codelist <- c("Z8","Z9")
```

Essentially, I am looking to find something like "Z8*" in any of the columns Code1 and Code2 and only keep those where this is TRUE. In the example above, ID row "C" where the code is Y94 would be the row filtered out as no Code column contains "Z8*" or "Z9*" anywhere. Here is a tabular format below for clarity with the TRUE/FALSE check I am trying to do (which will be filtered)

| ID | Code1 | Code2 | CHECK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Z84 |  | TRUE |
| B | Z85 |  | TRUE |
| C | Y94 |  | FALSE |
| D | Y94 | Z84 | TRUE |

I've been researching how to do this all morning but I can't find anything which quite does the job. Can anyone please suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use `if_any`

```
 library(tidyverse)

 df %>% 
   filter(if_any(Code1:Code2, ~str_detect(.x, str_c(codelist, collapse='|'))))

  ID Code1 Code2
1  A   Z84      
2  B   Z85      
3  D   Y94   Z84
```

---

```
df %>% 
  mutate(CHECK = if_any(Code1:Code2, ~str_detect(.x, str_c(codelist, collapse='|'))))

  ID Code1 Code2 CHECK
1  A   Z84        TRUE
2  B   Z85        TRUE
3  C   Y94       FALSE
4  D   Y94   Z84  TRUE
```

---

NB: The wildcard `*` should match something AFTER Z8 and not after Z. That is the reason for the wildcard `.`. Read more on regular expressions